# Значение строки в setContentView()

Tags: kotlin, layout

У меня есть строка, которая содержит название layout(допустим b = "one"), могу ли я  написать setContentView(R.layout.b), чтобы при выполнении кода мой нынешний layout сменился на one.xml.

Comment: Используйте для этого Intent или фрагменты

Answer (score 0):

Нет. R.layout.b это путь к файлу (как адрес папки на компьютере).

Если вы хотите вынести адрес к вашему макету в ссылку то выносить надо весь адрес:

```
int layout = R.layout.main_activity;
```

И тогда вызывать метод `setContentView(layout);`